# xml style sheet for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to get each employer and all his jobs in the job table
I'm having trouble of getting EmpID in the for-each
tried nested for-each but got conflict in select=""
i try to change the select statement to

> select="EmploymnetService/Employer

and add extra directory like this in each job value

> value-of select="@EmployerJobAds/JobAd/JobId"

but only got the first job for each employer obvious :-P

i have the folowing xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="employerStyle.xsl"?>
<EmploymnetService>
    <Employer employerId="1">
        <EmployerName>Ahmad</EmployerName>
        <EmployerAddress>Gaza</EmployerAddress>
        <EmployerEmail>ahmad.abuabdou@live.com</EmployerEmail>
        <EmployerPhone>0598787121</EmployerPhone>
        <EmployerJobAds >
            <JobAd JobId="1" >
                <jobTitle>Programmer</jobTitle>
                <jobDescription>Developer</jobDescription>
                <QualificationsRequired>
                    <QLevel>PhD</QLevel>
                    <QName>Developer</QName>
                    <QFaculty>IT</QFaculty>
                    <QUniversity>Azhar Univircity of Gaza</QUniversity>
                    <QGrade>Excellent</QGrade>
                    <gradDate>1995-04-19</gradDate>
                </QualificationsRequired>
                <ExperienceRequired>
                    <ExpPosition>Programmer</ExpPosition>
                    <expDescription>Developer</expDescription>
                    <expEmployer>Pro</expEmployer>
                    <expFrom>2012-10-26</expFrom>
                    <expTo>2016-11-26</expTo>
                </ExperienceRequired>
            </JobAd>
            <JobAd JobId="2" >
                <jobTitle>Programmer</jobTitle>
                <jobDescription>Developer</jobDescription>
                <QualificationsRequired>
                    <QLevel>PhD</QLevel>
                    <QName>Developer</QName>
                    <QFaculty>IT</QFaculty>
                    <QUniversity>Azhar Univircity of Gaza</QUniversity>
                    <QGrade>Excellent</QGrade>
                    <gradDate>1995-04-19</gradDate>
                </QualificationsRequired>
                <ExperienceRequired>
                    <ExpPosition>Programmer</ExpPosition>
                    <expDescription>Developer</expDescription>
                    <expEmployer>Pro</expEmployer>
                    <expFrom>2012-10-26</expFrom>
                    <expTo>2016-11-26</expTo>
                </ExperienceRequired>
            </JobAd>
        </EmployerJobAds>
    </Employer>

    <Employer employerId="2">
        <EmployerName>Ahmad</EmployerName>
        <EmployerAddress>Gaza</EmployerAddress>
        <EmployerEmail>ahmad.abuabdou@live.com</EmployerEmail>
        <EmployerPhone>0598787121</EmployerPhone>
        <EmployerJobAds >
            <JobAd JobId="3" >
                <jobTitle>Programmer</jobTitle>
                <jobDescription>Developer</jobDescription>
                <QualificationsRequired>
                    <QLevel>PhD</QLevel>
                    <QName>Developer</QName>
                    <QFaculty>IT</QFaculty>
                    <QUniversity>Azhar Univircity of Gaza</QUniversity>
                    <QGrade>Excellent</QGrade>
                    <gradDate>1995-04-19</gradDate>
                </QualificationsRequired>
                <ExperienceRequired>
                    <ExpPosition>Programmer</ExpPosition>
                    <expDescription>Developer</expDescription>
                    <expEmployer>Pro</expEmployer>
                    <expFrom>2012-10-26</expFrom>
                    <expTo>2016-11-26</expTo>
                </ExperienceRequired>
            </JobAd>
        </EmployerJobAds>
    </Employer>


</EmploymnetService>
```

and the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">

    <h2 align="center" style="color:green;">Employer</h2>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="700" align="center">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">EmployerID</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">EmployerName</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">EmployerAddress</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">EmployerEmail</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">EmployerPhone</th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="EmploymnetService/Employer">
      <xsl:sort select="EmployerName"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@employerId"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="EmployerName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="EmployerAddress"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="EmployerEmail"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="EmployerPhone"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>



    <h2 align="center" style="color:green;">Job Ad</h2>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="700" align="center">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">EmployerID</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">JobID</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">JobTitle</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">JobDescription</th>

     </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="EmploymnetService/Employer/EmployerJobAds/JobAd">
      <tr> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@employerId"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@JobId"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="jobTitle"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="jobDescription"/></td>
      </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>


    </table>


    <h2 align="center" style="color:green;">Qualification</h2>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="700" align="center">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
         <th style="text-align:left">JobID</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">QLevel</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">QName</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">QFaculty</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">QUniversity</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">QGrade</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">gradDate</th>
     </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="EmploymnetService/Employer/EmployerJobAds/JobAd">
       <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@JobId"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="QualificationsRequired/QLevel"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="QualificationsRequired/QName"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="QualificationsRequired/QFaculty"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="QualificationsRequired/QUniversity"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="QualificationsRequired/QGrade"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="QualificationsRequired/gradDate"/></td>

       </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>


    <h2 align="center" style="color:green;">Experience Required</h2>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="700" align="center">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
         <th style="text-align:left">JobID</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">ExpPosition</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">expDescription</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">expEmployer</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">expFrom</th>
         <th style="text-align:left">expTo</th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="EmploymnetService/Employer/EmployerJobAds/JobAd">
      <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@JobId"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="ExperienceRequired/ExpPosition"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="ExperienceRequired/expDescription"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="ExperienceRequired/expEmployer"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="ExperienceRequired/expFrom"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="ExperienceRequired/expTo"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this what i got so far
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSaYn.jpg)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the HTML for the output you are expecting? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm having trouble of getting EmpID in the for-each

In the `<xsl:for-each select="EmploymnetService/Employer/EmployerJobAds/JobAd">` block, change:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="@employerId"/></td>
```

to:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Employer/@employerId"/></td>
```